# Error: Building package bzip2:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED

Tags: vcpkg

I'm new to vcpkg and I am trying to install gdal but it seems to fail while trying to install bzip2

when I run

```
.\vcpkg install bzip2
```

I get the following error message

> The following packages will be built and installed:
>       bzip2[core]:x86-windows
>   Starting package 1/1: bzip2:x86-windows
>   Building package bzip2[core]:x86-windows...
>   -- Downloading http://www.bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz...
>   -- Downloading http://www.bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz... Failed. Status: 56;"Failure when receiving data from the peer"
>   CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_download_distfile.cmake:151 (message):
>
> ```
> Failed to download file.
>   If you use a proxy, please set the HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY environment
>   variables to "https://user:password@your-proxy-ip-address:port/".
>   Otherwise, please submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues
> ```
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     ports/bzip2/portfile.cmake:4 (vcpkg_download_distfile)
>     scripts/ports.cmake:71 (include)
>
> Error: Building package bzip2:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
>   Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `.\vcpkg update`, then
>   submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
>     Package: bzip2:x86-windows
>     Vcpkg version: 0.0.113-nohash
>
> Additionally, attach any relevant sections from the log files above

I'm not using a proxy so I am not sure why this is failing